# How to extract a number/status code from "Netflix Conductor" workflow output/task output parameters?

Tags: java, workflow, orchestration, netflix-conductor

I am using Netflix Conductor's HTTP task in my workflow to call one of the third-party APIs. For success scenarios, I am able to retrieve the status code as "200" in the task output, but for failure scenarios, the status code is not getting printed in the task/workflow output response. But, I am getting the error message in the "*resonForIncompletion*" parameter in the task summary which includes the error message in the string format, and this has a status code as well in a few cases. Below is the failure/error scenario response from the task output.

```
Sample:
{
  "response": "java.lang.Exception: 404 Not Found: \"{}\""
}

JSON response:
{
"taskId": "cd31283b-f209-4cfc-a024-02503300e9d8",
*"reasonForIncompletion": "Failed to invoke HTTP task due to: java.lang.Exception: 404 Not Found: \"{}\""*,
}
```

I would need to extract 404 from this "reasonForIncompletion" parameter and should send this as a status code in the workflow/task output prameters. Could someone please help me with this.?

Comment: Are you sure the structure of `reasonForIncompletion` value won't change in the future?

Comment: Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("Failed to invoke HTTP task due to: java.lang.Exception: 404 Not Found: \"{}\"");
        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(matcher.group(0));
        }

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! This structure might change in the future for other error responses. But in my case, there are a few default cases that would return the status code in "reasonForIncompletion" param. To handle those, would require extracting the status code from the string.